# ¿Cómo se le llama al afijo "oji-" en, por ejemplo, "ojiabierto"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, terminología, compuestos

¿Cómo se llama la transformación de *ojo* en *oji-*? Por ejemplo *ojiabierto*. O bien *ali-* en *aliabierto.*

Comment: Tras los edits de esta pregunta, puede que sea necesaria aclaración de si lo que preguntas es como se llama una **parte de la palabra** (por ejemplo "oji" o la "i" de "oji" en "ojiabierto") o el **proceso** por el cual de "ojo" + "abierto" se obtiene "oj**i**abierto" (o si preguntas algo completamente diferente a esas dos opciones).

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/por-qu%c3%a9-las-partes-del-cuerpo-toman-una-i-antes-de-componerlas-con-un-adjetiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Oji" en *ojiabierto* no es realmente un prefijo. Un prefijo es un morfema que se añade a una raíz para formar una palabra diferente (el prefijo cambia el significado de la palabra):

> **ex**marido, **vice**presidente, **pre**pago, **anti**social

"Ojiabierto" es una palabra compuesta (como "rojiblanco", "sacacorchos", etc.). Las palabras compuestas se pueden formar de varias maneras:

- **Sustantivo + Sustantivo:** compraventa
- **Sustantivo + Adjetivo:** pelirrojo
- **Adjetivo + Sustantivo:** bajorrelieve
- **Verbo + Sustantivo:** sacacorchos
- **Adjetivo + Adjetivo:** rojiblanco
- **Adverbio + Adjetivo:** malhumorado
- **Verbo + Verbo:** tejemaneje
- **Pronombre + Verbo:** quienquiera

Así que "oji" en "ojiabierto" es una sustantivo que es la primera parte de la palabra compuesta "ojo - abierto". Igual con "aliabierto"  (abierto de alas). "Ali" es un sustantivo. Técnicamente son la primera palabra de una palabra compuesta.

Aparte, puede que el término que estés buscando sea ["**afijo**"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afijo), que es un tipo de prefijo.

Comment: Normalmente se llama elemento compositivo. Suelen preferir las vocales *i* o *u* en posición final si no son elementos terminales.

Comment: ¿Entonces *el afijo correspondiente a ojo* es la única descripción para *oji-*?

Comment: No sé si he entendido la pregunta, pero me da la sensación de que el usuario c.p. no pregunta por eso, sino por el proceso según el cual la 'o' de ojo (o la 'a' de ala) se transforman en íes. Si se trata de asimilación fonética o de otro proceso.

Comment: @guillem, releyendo la pregunta (pre y post edits), creo que pregunta por el nombre de un componente o parte de una palabra, no por un proceso. Si bien, al momento de escribir estas líneas, el título de la pregunta y el cuerpo no coinciden del todo ("transformación de ojo a oji" pero nomenclatura de "ali- en aliabierto"). Antes de los edits estaba claro para mi lo que se preguntaba. Después de los edits no.

Comment: Supongo que pillé la pregunta con los edits ya hechos y me pareció que realmente preguntaba lo que responde @angus o algo similar (aunque hay mucho de interpretación subjetiva en que me lo pareciese). Edit: al menos me ha servido para aprender a usar la arroba.

Comment: Tras los edits, el post de angus respondo mejor que el mío a la pregunta. Tiene mi +1.

Comment: Es cierto, no pregunté por eso, pero esta respuesta fue necesaria y muy útil para que yo pudiera formular la pregunta de manera más concreta.

Comment: @c.p., dejaré esta respuesta entonces tal cual está, pese a los downvotes, ya que parece aportar algo. Si la respuesta de Angus responde completamente a tu pregunta considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada. Si no, siempre puedes añadir más ejemplos en la pregunta para clarificar lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 7):

Esa `i` se llama “vocal de enlace” y creo que no hay un verbo específico que denote formar un compuesto que la lleve. Esto es lo que la *Gramática* de la R.A.E. dice sobre estos compuestos:

> **11.2.1f**     Los segmentos de un compuesto aparecen a veces unidos por un elemento de ENLACE. Se usa la vocal *-i-* en los compuestos coordinativos formados con las pau­tas N*-i-*N (*ajiaceite*), V*-i-*V (*subibaja*) y A*-i-*A (*agridulce*), pero también en algunos su­bordinativos, como N*-i-*-V (*perniquebrar*). En los compuestos formados por elementos grecolatinos, el elemento de enlace suele ser *-o-* para los términos de origen griego (*cartógrafo, dermatólogo*) e *-i-* para los de origen latino (*apicultor, fratricida*).