# ¿Por qué las partes del cuerpo toman una -i- antes de componerlas con un adjetivo?

Tags: etimología, sufijos, compuestos

Acabo de ver en una de estas imágenes que pone el Windows 10 de fondo un pájaro llamado "monarca nuquinegro". Eso me llevó a pensar que las partes del cuerpo (y no sé si pasa con otros sustantivos) toman una *i* antes de ser compuestas con un adjetivo. Se me ocurre *[patizambo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SAELsfA)*, por ejemplo, aunque también existen *[patiblanco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S9K6tOa)*, *[manirroto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OEadUod)*, *[ojijunto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qy1OmcA)*, e incluso en términos inventados como "ojiplático" o "[cabecicubo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_cabecicubos)".

¿Cuál es la causa de esta *i* ante adjetivos? ¿De dónde viene? ¿Sucede con otros sustantivos que no denoten partes del cuerpo?

Entiendo que esta *i* es diferente de la que aparece en compuestos como *[blanquinegro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5fWwzCL)*, en los que la *i* es la conjunción *y* integrada en la palabra.

Comment: También tenemos "petirrojo". Creo que el uso de esa "i" es un mecanismo de neutralización del género, al mismo tiempo que facilita la unión desde una perspectiva fonética.

Comment: La *i* es efectivamente la partícula compositora en castellano.  No creo que sea para neutralizar el género (eso sí se hace por medio de la *-o-* neutra en decir, por ejemplo *gallegoportuguesa*), sino al suprimir la vocal original y reemplazarla con *i*, es evidente que se trata de un concepto singular y no una mera pata blanca, etc.

Comment: Tienes razón, @guifa. Más que neutralizar el género, esa *i* le quita autonomía al primer componente. Otro ejemplo: *pelilargo*.

Comment: otro ejemplo: `pelirrojo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según [este interesante trabajo de investigación](http://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/DICE/article/view/DICE9797110307A/12889) que he encontrado en Internet, el uso de esa "i" no está en absoluto limitado a partes del cuerpo y puede observarse en palabras compuestas de múltiples significados.

Según dicen los autores, en los compuestos **de origen latino** prevalece la desinencia "i", mientras que en los de origen griego el enlace ocurre con "o". Tenemos así pares como: av**i**cultura/ornit**o**logía, morb**í**fico/pat**ó**geno, calor**í**metro/term**ó**metro, pesc**í**voro/icti**ó**fago, un**i**color/mon**o**cromo, vin**i**cultura/en**o**logía.

En cuanto al origen de esa "i", dicen los autores:

> Sentado el principio de que los compuestos latinos se integran usualmente
>   por la vocal temática *i* cabe preguntarse de dónde deriva dicho cambio interno.
>   Aunque el campo parece poco estudiado, una filóloga de enjundia sugiere
>   que deriva «posiblemente del genitivo latino». Desde el punto de vista
>   morfosemántico, el genitivo latino tenía varias funciones que frecuentemente
>   en las lenguas romances establecen el régimen con la preposición "de", lo cual,
>   bien mirado, tiene validez para los compuestos atributivos, ya que «ojinegro»
>   designa al ser **de** ojos negros o negro **de** ojos.

Comment: La _Gramática_ de la RAE concuerda en el origen latino (puedes ver mi respuesta), pero limita bastante las posibles construcciones. Date cuenta de que hablo de combinaciones de sustantivo más adjetivo (lo que la _Gramática_ denomina "N-i-A"). En tus ejemplos la combinación es entre dos sustantivos ("ave" más "cultura") o son compuestos con prefijos o sufijos conocidos ("-ímetro", "-ívoro", "uni-"). No constituyen el mismo caso pues que el propuesto en la pregunta.

Comment: @Charlie La primera parte de mi respuesta fue general, a modo de introducción. La segunda abordó específicamente el caso de los compuestos "N-i-A" por los que preguntabas. Personalmente, estoy al menos bastante satisfecho de haber encontrado en Internet un artículo tan completo y específico sobre el tema.

Answer (score 3):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, aquí estamos hablando de una clase restringida de compuestos: los adjetivos formados por una fusión de sustantivo + adjetivo. En un libro [sobre compuestos en español](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=CSpzAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140) encuentro un largo análisis de esta clase de compuestos.

Si bien estos compuestos son casi todos de la forma N-*i*-Adj, algunos no tienen *-i-* intermedia, como *cabizbajo*. Sin embargo todos pertenecen claramente a un mismo tipo, referido casi siempre a partes del cuerpo y con otras varias características semánticas.

Estos compuestos no son de origen latino, porque los adjetivos compuestos latinos no se formaban de esa manera sino con el orden adjetivo + sustantivo. Hay ejemplos similares, pero no idénticos, en italiano y catalán, pero no se trata de una derivación productiva (mientras que en español sí lo es). En catalán la forma preferida del sustantivo es la forma completa (*alallarg* "alilargo", *camacurt* "piernicorto").

Según este análisis, lo que vemos en castellano es el radical del sustantivo sin desinencia, al cual se le añade por motivos de composición la *-i-*, y luego el adjetivo.

A fines del siglo XIII aparecen en castellano formas con la raíz desnuda como *tiestherido* ("herido en la cabeza", figurativo por "loco"), con la raíz acortada como *racorto* (con *ra < rabo*), y con la raíz desnuda más una vocal intermedia, que puede ser *-i-* (*barbirrapado*) o también *-e-* (*cuellealuo* "de cuello albo, cuelliblanco"). Entre el siglo XVI y el XVII aparecen muchos más adjetivos de este tipo y quedan descartadas las varias formas alternativas en favor de la moderna, con *-i-* intermedia.

Comment: María Moliner dice que la "i" en compuestos atributivos (aquellos de valor adjetivo formados por sustantivo + adjetivo, que son por los que pregunta específicamente Charlie) posiblemente provenga del **genitivo latino**, donde "i" sería equiparable a "de", por ejemplo, alicaído = **de** alas caídas.

Answer (score 3):

Dado que nadie la ha citado aún, quiero comentar que este tipo de construcciones se trata ampliamente en la *Nueva Gramática* de la RAE, [en los párrafos 11.7h y siguientes](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QeRtDHlzpjSdVvlJ).

> La pauta N-*i*-A es la más productiva del español entre todas las que dan lugar a compuestos adjetivales de sustantivo y adjetivo. A ella pertenecen *barbilampiño*, *bracicorto*, *narilargo*, *ojizarco*, *pernilargo* y otros muchos adjetivos que se predican mayoritariamente de las personas y los animales.

La *Gramática* concuerda [con Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23049/12637) en cuanto al origen latino de la construcción:

> Este esquema se remota al latín (*barbirāsus*), donde alternaba con la pauta que presentaba el sustantivo en segunda posición: *aureispīnus* ('de espina dorada'), longimănus ('de mano larga'), *versipellis* ('que muda de piel'). La pauta A-i-N se ha conservado en español en *curvilíneo* o *rectilíneo*. La vocal *-i-* de estos compuestos procedía de un genitivo latino, pero ya en latín se propagó de los sustantivos que la contenían (*agrilĕgus*, *coeligĕnus*, *florĭfer*) a otros en los que no estaba presente, pero que la aceptaron como vocal de enlace, como *aquilĭfer* (de *aquĭla, -ae*); *fructĭfer* (de *fructus, -us*); *fluctĭger*, *fluctisŏnus* y *fluctivăgus* (de *fluctus, -us*); *herbĭfer* (de *herba, -ae*); *terrĭgena* (de *terra, -ae*), y otros muchos.

Sobre su uso actual:

> Se han observado algunas restricciones en lo relativo al tipo de sustantivo con el que se forman estos compuestos. Constituyen el grupo más numeroso los que se refieren a partes del cuerpo de las personas y de los animales.

Pero no se limita a esto:

> El nombre se refiere a una prenda de vestir, en lugar de a una parte del cuerpo, en *faldicorta* ('corta de faldas') o *capipardo* ('de capa parda' y, por extensión, 'del pueblo bajo').

Sobre el adjetivo:

> También existen restricciones que afectan a los adjetivos con los que se forman los compuestos N-*i*-A. Muchos de ellos designan colores (*albo, blanco, negro, rojo, rubio, zarco*); otros expresan propiedades físicas, normalmente referidas al tamaño o la forma de lo que se caracteriza: *alto, ancho, bajo, corto, gordo, espeso, largo, redondo*, como en *barbiespeso, cabeciancho, cañihueco, carirredondo* u *ojimoreno*. En general, son mucho más numerosos en esta pauta los adjetivos que expresan carencias o defectos (*cojo, hueco, ralo, tuerto, zambo*) que los que destacan algún aspecto positivo (*alegre, lindo, tierno*).

El adjetivo además puede ser un participio, como en *barbiteñido, boquiabierto, carilavado, cuellierguido, labihendido, manirroto*...

Comment: Quiero entender que encontraste la respuesta después de hacer la pregunta, ¿verdad? Si no, o nos estás poniendo a prueba o estamos ante un caso de doble personalidad, el Charlie preguntador y el Charlie respondedor. :)

Comment: @Gustavson reconozco que ha habido ocasiones en las que he hecho preguntas sabiendo la respuesta, simplemente para darle vida al sitio, pero esta no ha sido una de esas ocasiones. La respuesta la encontré más tarde, pero preferí esperar a que la gente respondiera para tener más opiniones. Me ha gustado el debate generado, y tu respuesta en particular me pareció bastante acertada (con independencia del comentario que te puse antes).

Comment: Trataré de ser más preciso la próxima vez, pero creo que muchas veces una introducción puede ser esclarecedora: no desvía, sino que lleva al tema. Simplemente es una humilde postura pedagógica que suelo ejercitar.

Comment: @Gustavson entiendo, ¡gracias por tu aclaración!

Answer (score 0):

No existe una norma general. Se utiliza para formar un adjetivo compuesto de 3 palabras donde "i" representa la palabra "y".

Por ejemplo:

"Pata" y "Corta" = "Paticorta" ; 
"Ojo" y "junto" = "Ojijunto" ;

Como puedes observar, fonéticamente, al unir estas palabras, algunas vocales son omitidas porque favorece la pronunciación de la misma.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta, y bienvenido! Investigando un poco he visto una explicación diferente para este tipo de construcciones. ¿Podrías citar tus fuentes para la respuesta?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida. Me he basado en simple sentido comun. Echale un ojo a este libro donde viene bien explicado: https://issuu.com/ceciliap5/docs/206371620-varela-ortega-morfologia-

Comment: En la pregunta ya pone como ejemplo  *blanquinegro* que es *blanco y negro* pero *paticorto*, por ejemplo, no es *pata y corta* sino *patas cortas*, no hay conjunción, lo mísmo para los demás ejemplos. El documento que enlazas no dice lo mismo que tú en la parte que habla de estos casos.

Comment: Efectivamente, en la página 79 del libro que enlazas se explica, pero no como argumentas. En el libro se dice que en esos compuestos la vocal final (de "ojo", "pata" y demás) se sustituye por _i_, pero no que esa _i_ sea la conjunción _y_.

Comment: Ojo!! El libro que enlace previamente lo descubri tras responder a esta pregunta. Nada que ver con mi respuesta. simplemente intentando ayudar a resolver la pregunta e investigando. No mas. Ahora se que mi respuesta no era valida, pero el enlace si :)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya hay una respuesta citando la RAE pero esta fuente que encontré me pareció igual interesante. Es un [documento](https://is.muni.cz/th/145940/ff_b/diplomova_prace.pdf) acerca de la composición de palabras. En él se explica lo siguiente:

> ... las vocales átonas finales [a], [e] y [o] pertenecientes al primer constituyente se pueden sustituir por [i]:
>   carirredondo, verdiazul, maniflojo. Pero en realidad no existe ninguna teoría que explique sus condiciones de aplicación de manera satisfactoria.

Se cita además en ese texto:

> "«Se han dado varias interpretaciones para explicar el papel que desempeña la [i] en este tipo de formaciones. Por ejemplo, se le ha atribuido una función
>   “conjuntiva“ que, aunque probable desde la perspectiva semántica en formas como carricoche- parafraseado como: es un coche y es un carro- o coliflor, no se justifica
>   en otros casos, especialmente en algunos compuestos adjetivales, porque en ellos no se atisba claramente ninguna razón de tipo semántico o fonológico.»"