# ¿Por qué hay una "i" en la palabra "pelirrojo"?

Tags: etimología

Me gustaría saber ¿por qué la palabra "pelirrojo" tiene una "i"?, ya que sin duda esta palabra está compuesta de "pelo" y "rojo".

¿Es solamente porque suena mejor así, o hay otra explicación más profunda? ¿Se les ocurre otros ejemplos?

A mí sí, aunque me parece que viene del latín. Por ejemplo, un destornillador *cruciforme*.

Comment: Segun https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogaci%C3%B3n no hay que dejar un espacio justo después de un signo de apertura de interrogacion. Y en la frase interrogativa, creo que es "porque": me parece que mi "porque" tiene la misma funcion que en la frase siguiente: "¿corregiste mi frase porque te parece incorrecta?" al contrario de "¿por qué corregiste mi frase?".

Comment: Creo que alguien hizo la misma pregunta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/por-qu%c3%a9-las-partes-del-cuerpo-toman-una-i-antes-de-componerlas-con-un-adjetiv?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Cuestión: ¿ Por qué la palabra "pelirrojo" tiene una "i"?

---

- Pelirrojo, ("que tiene el pelo bermejo" rojo, semi-obscuro y saturado, basado en un color cobrizo)".
- Pelirrojo, que tiene el pelo de color rojizo, entre cobre y caoba. La palabra ha estado en uso desde principios del S. XVI. Se asocia con un color de piel claro, pecas, sensibilidad a la luz y un color de ojos marrones o azules de tonos claros .
- Pelirrojo Compuesto asintáctico, es decir, en este caso formada por dos palabras de nuestra lengua. Pelo (Sustantivo) + Rojo (Adjetivo).
- Cabellera, conjunto de pelos en la cabeza. Cabello, del Lat. Capillus  de caput (Cabeza) + pilus (Pelo). Pelo de la cabeza.
- Pelirrojo Lat. "Flavis pilis". Dentro de la palabra "Flavis" existía una gama amplia de colores que iban del castaño rojizo hasta el pelirrojo, pasando por el rubio, pues el pelirrojo participa tanto del rojo como del amarillo. "Pilus Rusus", "Pelo Rojo". Lat. "Rubicundus -a - um", dorado, "rubicundo", rojo obscuro, rojizo. "Rufus", rojo, pelirrojo, "Rubidus", rojizo.
- **Pelo**, derivado del Latin "pilus" y este del griego "pilos". "Pelotón de pelos" Ant. Expr. Lat. "Pilorum globus"

Aunque decimos " pelo + rojo ", en realidad seria " pelos + rojos" ya que el cabello esta compuesto de un numero indeterminado de finos "pili". Es lógico pensar que alguna forma de los plurales o casos de la palabra en Latín para pelo, **Pīlus - Pīlī**, pasase al Latín Hispánico para referirse a alguien o a un grupo de personas con estas características, conservando algún caso en "i" de los plurales y no la "o", en este caso, más propia del singular.

---

**Pīlus - Pīlī**

2.ª declinación (-us)

```
   Singular - Plural
```

> Nominativo    pīlus   -   pīlī
>
> Vocativo  pīle    -   pīlī
>
> Acusativo pīlum   -   pīlōs
>
> Genitivo  pīlī    -   pīlōrum
>
> Dativo        pīlō    -   pīlīs
>
> Ablativo  pīlō    -   pīlīs

Answer (score 0):

Muchas palabras que se refieren a órganos toman la terminación "i" cuando se forma un adjetivo que califica ese órgano, pero el adjetivo compuesto termina calificando a la persona entera, no solo al órgano.

Alguien que tiene el pelo rojo: es un pelirrojo.

Alguien que tiene las manos largas: es un manilargo.

Alguien que tiene las patas chuecas: es un patichueco.

Alguien que tiene las cejas juntas: es un cejijunto.

Alguien que tiene la boca ancha: es un boquiancho.

Alguien que tiene los ojos azules: es un ojiazul.

Alguien que tiene la cabeza dura: es un cabeciduro.